# Trying to redirect country specific users without affecting search engine crawlers

Tags: javascript, redirect, cloudflare, googlebot, cloudflare-workers

I'm trying prevent US visitors from accessing non-US pages by redirecting them using a Cloudflare Worker, however, I still want to allow search engines to crawl the entire site so they will bypass the redirect.

Cloudflare gives me the [visitors country](https://developers.cloudflare.com/workers/runtime-apis/request/#incomingrequestcfproperties) and if the visitor is a [verified bot](https://radar.cloudflare.com/traffic/verified-bots).

The site has all US page URLs prefixed with `/us/` so I can perform a basic regex to check what part of the site they are trying to access.

So this is what I have implemented...

```js
export default {
  async fetch(request) {

    // Get the visitors country code.
    // @link https://developers.cloudflare.com/workers/runtime-apis/request/
    const visitorCountry = request.cf?.country;

    // Get the bot management status.
    // @link https://developers.cloudflare.com/bots/reference/bot-management-variables/#workers-variables
    // @link https://radar.cloudflare.com/traffic/verified-bots
    const requestIsVerifiedBot = request?.cf?.botManagement?.verifiedBot;

    const requestUrl = new URL(request.url);
    const requestUrlIsUs = requestUrl.pathname.match(/^\/us\/?$|^\/us\/.*$/i)?.length;

    // If the visitor is from the US, and they are accessing a non-US page, and they are not a verified robot.
    if (visitorCountry === 'US' && !requestUrlIsUs && !requestIsVerifiedBot) {
      return Response.redirect('https://example.com/us/', 301); // Go back to the US homepage.
    }

    // Continue through.
    return fetch(request);
  }
}
```

The redirect is working as expected, however, the verified bot condition always appears to fail so crawlers are also being redirected. I'm not sure why this is happening, based on the Cloudflare documentation this should work as expected.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Have you enabled Bot Management on your account? This is a paid feature. Due to a historical accident that's hard to fix without breaking people, the `request.cf.botManagement` property always appears but contains dummy values if you do not have Bot Management enabled on your account.

Comment: @KentonVarda you are right! Thank you! Repost you comment as an answer and I can accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to enable Bot Management on your account. This is a paid Cloudflare feature.

Unfortunately, due to a historical accident, `request.cf.botManagement` shows up even if you have not subscribed to Bot Management, but in this case it contains dummy values -- the content will be the same regardless of the request. We (Cloudflare) would like to remove the property entirely when you don't have a subscription, but some Worker scripts in the wild are accidentally depending on this field existing even though they haven't subscribed to the feature, so getting rid of it is complicated.

Comment: Is there an Cloudflare blog artical on the historical accident? Would be an interesting read!

Comment: I'm not aware of one. But basically due to a bug the data was accidentally sent to all workers regardless of subscription and by the time the problem was noticed it couldn't be reversed without breaking some live workers. We try very hard not to make changes that break code which is already deployed... so we had to use dummy data instead. Eventually this will probably be cleaned up using a compatibility flag.